# Как называется тип, когда возвращается jsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть функция которая возвращает вёрстку. Но возвращает она не один элемент, а множество. Поэтому у меня не работает тип  ReactElement.
Какой должен быть возвращаемый тип этой функции?

Comment: Может быть `ReactElement[]`, можно еще попробовать через IDE посмотреть, возможно она сама подскажет выведенный тип.

Comment: Можете добавить пример этой функции, чтобы было понятно, что она возвращается, множество чего именно? И от этого будет проще плясать отвечающим